# istioctl deploying to EKS -- how to NOT create an external load balancer?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks

I am using istioctl to install istio in an EKS cluster. However, for the moment I will be using an nginx ingress for externally facing services. How can I just deploy the istio service internally, or at least avoid the automatically created ELB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by editing [istio-ingressgateway](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/).

Change [service type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) from

**LoadBalancer** -> Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer

to

**ClusterIP** -> Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster.

Let's edit ingressgateway

```
kubectl edit svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
```

Then please change the type from LoadBalancer to ClusterIP and **#** or **delete**  every nodePort since You won't use them anymore and it have to be # or deleted so You could actually edit the file, without it, it fails to edit and nothing is happening.

**EDIT**

> I can do this at install with istioctl using a values.yaml file?

Yes, it's possible.

This is a value You need to change:

> values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway.type

example

Creating manifest to apply istio demo profile with ClusterIP

```
istioctl manifest generate --set profile=demo --set values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway.type="ClusterIP" > $HOME/generated-manifest.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks! Presumably I can do this at install with istioctl using a values.yaml file? I'm creating an auto deploy script and changing type after init may mean I also have to change the script delete the auto created ELB.

Comment: Hi @shaunc, it's possible. I made an EDIT in my answer, check it out.